# Finding keywords in a sentence

Tags: java, algorithm, keyword, similarity

I'm trying to implement few algorithms for measuring similarity between two sentences. I think it would be helpful if I had some kind of expanded representation of a sentence.

We could get this expanded representation with google/bing search, but putting whole sentence as a keyword doesn't give good results, especially if sentence is long. So I was thinking that finding keywords in a sentence and using them as search terms would improve our results.

Anybody aware of an algorithm for finding keywords in a sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused: are you looking for **string similarity measures** or for **keywords extraction algorithms**?

Comment: Are you lookinig for regular expressions ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions

Comment: I'm looking for keywords extraction algorithms.

Comment: Then use a regular expression with the keywords you want and compare the number of matches...

Comment: I want to extract keywords automatically - I don't know what are possible keywords in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Lucene**](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) can handle that extraction as well as the comparison.

Comment: I now use Lucenes StandardAnalyzer to remove (English) stop words and tokenize the sentence. Then I extract nouns from the list of tokens and use them as a search query.